# how can i fetch a value from a text which is an incomplete xml file and then store it in a variable

Tags: xml, xmllint

I am having an issue while formatting an incomplete XML file in to a proper tagged XML, so that I can easily fetch the XML value inside a tag from it.

Output text is like this:

```
Input parameters 
         User       : abcd
         User       : abc@1234
         User Agent : pqr Server/12.0/1.0
         file  Name : tmpfile.9133
         Timeout    : 5
         Nr  thread : 1
         Nr resends : 1
_____ Adresses:____
http://localhost:12345/Mrr
File tmpfile.9133 Contains  1  requests.
start thread 0
---------------- Sending --------------------
<methodCall>
<methodName>Test1</methodName>
<params>
<param>
<value>
<struct>
<member>
<name>row1</name>
<value>
<i4>1</i4>
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>main1</name>
<value>ADM</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>originTransactionID</name>
<value>464372231</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>min</name>
<value>99912345678</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>originTimeStamp</name>
<value>
<dateTime.iso8601>20150929T02:20:32+0300</dateTime.iso8601>
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>main2</name>
<value>
<array>
<data>
<value>
<struct>
<member>
<name>ID</name>
<value>
<i4>115001</i4>
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>ValueNew</name>
<value>
<string>0</string>
</value>
</member>
</struct>
</value>
</data>
</array>
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>originHostName</name>
<value>rat</value>
</member>
</struct>
</value>
</param>
</params>
</methodCall>

---------------- Recived  --------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: abc
Date: Mon, 28 Sep 2015 23:20:32 GMT
Server: xyz
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=15du5xtimqk42qoeej6o8l0u6;Path=/
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 1489
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><methodResponse><params><param><value><struct><member><name>fsdfsdfsdf</name><value><array><data><value><i4>536871492</i4></value></data></array></value></member><member><name>sdfsdfsdf</name><value><array><data><value><i4>0</i4></value></data></array></value></member><member><name>txnID</name><value><string>464372231</string></value></member><member><name>responseCode</name><value><i4>0</i4></value></member><member><name>info</name><value><array><data><value><struct><member><name>ID</name><value><i4>115001</i4></value></member><member><name>Value</name><value><string>0</string></value></member><member><name>Information</name><value><array><data><value><struct><member><name>ID</name><value><i4>11500101</i4></value></member><member><name>TSource</name><value><i4>3</i4></value></member><member><name>TValue</name><value><string>524288000</string></value></member></struct></value><value><struct><member><name>TID</name><value><i4>11500102</i4></value></member><member><name>TSource</name><value><i4>3</i4></value></member><member><name>TValue</name><value><string>519045120</string></value></member></struct></value></data></array></value></member></struct></value></data></array></value></member></struct></value></param></params></methodResponse>
----------------------------------------------
```

Now I want to perform 2 operations:

1. make this output to be trim from the mark  `---------------- Recived  --------------------`   till end and store it in a seperate variable.
2. Then trim this file so that it is a perfect XML file with proper tags and all... i.e. starting from `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` to `</methodResponse>`.

I want to do the above two tasks on Solaris server only. I tried using `xmllint --xpath` but seems like xpath is not in the package. So please suggest any other way.

Answer (score 1):

The official answer is - you don't. Broken XML is fatal by design. Any parser that *fixes* broken XML is also - by definition - not an XML parser.

You should reject the XML and tell your 'upstream' that their data is corrupt - because it is. Push very hard on this, because a hacky bodge to forward fix XML is very bad news for long term stability and reliability of your code. It might one day just break randomly.

Having said that - your XML isn't broken - it's just wrapped up in a text file. And it's missing stuff like declarations, but that isn't actually formally required.

So you can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml; 
while ( <> ) { 
    if ( m/-- Sending --/ .. /-- Recived  --/ ) { 
        next if m/----/;  ##skip the sending/recived lines
        next if m/^\s*$/;   #skip any blank lines
        $xml .= $_; #add the current line to "$xml". 
    }
}

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( 'pretty_print' => 'indented_a' ) 
$twig -> parse ( $xml );
$twig -> set_encoding('utf-8');
$twig -> set_xml_version('1.0');
$twig -> print;
```

You *will* need an XML library - I've use `XML::Twig` because it's widely available and in some cases installed by default/available through your package manager. (You should be able to fetch it from CPAN if it isn't).

You don't actually need it though - the `print $xml` will give you valid XML that you can then use with whatever tool you were going to anyway.

This - given your source data as above - spits out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>Test1</methodName>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
          <member>
            <name>row1</name>
            <value>
              <i4>1</i4>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>main1</name>
            <value>ADM</value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>originTransactionID</name>
            <value>464372231</value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>min</name>
            <value>99912345678</value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>originTimeStamp</name>
            <value>
              <dateTime.iso8601>20150929T02:20:32+0300</dateTime.iso8601>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>main2</name>
            <value>
              <array>
                <data>
                  <value>
                    <struct>
                      <member>
                        <name>ID</name>
                        <value>
                          <i4>115001</i4>
                        </value>
                      </member>
                      <member>
                        <name>ValueNew</name>
                        <value>
                          <string>0</string>
                        </value>
                      </member>
                    </struct>
                  </value>
                </data>
              </array>
            </value>
          </member>
          <member>
            <name>originHostName</name>
            <value>rat</value>
          </member>
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodCall>
```